# How do I execute a program in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I know this is terribly simple.  I'm on Windows 10.  I have tried Enter, CTRL-Enter, and others.  I have created a JS build environment using Node, but I just can't seem to run code and get any output.

Comment: You might have guessed, I am brand new to programming.  Sublime Text 2 is my first editor.

Comment: Are you looking for Ctrl+B?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Terminal](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminal). You need to have [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) first.

Sublime Text is a great editor.